# Unable to Connect to Google Colab with Jupyter Notebook from Google Cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to port forward from google cloud and open a jupyter notebook server to connect to google cloud in a local runtime. However, despite several changes, I've never been able to connect to it. For reference, I've downgraded tornado, updated ipynb, and tried several variations of the jupyter notebook command line. I've been basing the port forward on this link: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html. Does anyone have any clue on how to help me connect it? I've listed the error code below when I tried to connect to the local runtime in the google colab notebook.

```
[I 06:46:20.069 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree?token=f26bb1a6846c91773100e6115910278fa93a1cebf8e3cd89 (::1) 0.55ms
[W 06:46:20.097 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 06:46:20.097 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs (::1) 0.65ms referer=None
[I 06:46:24.475 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=2d85dada2f8b613eefeeaa235084afd32a060bb7467838a2 (::1) 0.39ms
[I 06:46:24.670 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=2d85dada2f8b613eefeeaa235084afd32a060bb7467838a2 (::1) 0.40ms
[I 06:46:24.692 NotebookApp] Kernel started: cd40b67b-d245-4a59-afb1-a97225bb5520
[I 06:46:25.025 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=2d85dada2f8b613eefeeaa235084afd32a060bb7467838a2 (::1) 0.39ms
[I 06:46:25.029 NotebookApp] proxying WebSocket connection to: ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/cd40b67b-d245-4a59-afb1-a97225bb5520/channels?session_id=2329eda405e94407ba5e9806cf2c3bc6&jupyter_http_over_ws_auth_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F%3Ftoken%3D2d85dada2f8b613eefeeaa235084afd32a060bb7467838a2
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7fd65c233170>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 605, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 535, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda: self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
[W 06:46:35.034 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from cd40b67b-d245-4a59-afb1-a97225bb5520
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback (<zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x7fd65f3adc90>, <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7fd65f348b90>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Comment: The error 403 is an authentication error issue. For this reason, I need to ask have you authenticated your request such as described in the documentation [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html#:~:text=In%20Colaboratory%2C%20click%20the%20%22Connect,connected%20to%20your%20local%20runtime.)?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Sorry, what exactly do you mean by that? I already followed everything in the documentation, but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I mean the step 3 of the link I shared. So you authenticate your request for the connection. Have you done it as per the [documentation](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html#:~:text=In%20Colaboratory%2C%20click%20the%20%22Connect,connected%20to%20your%20local%20runtime.)?